# Service Fabric Not able to open the website once the service and frontend is deployed

Tags: azure

I deployed a sample "WordCount" Azure sample to service fabric cluster. I see that both the service: fabric://wordcount/WordCountService and fabric://WordCount/WordCountWebService are running OK, however, when I try to access the app from browser with below URL, the app does not come up.

http://tenantname.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/wordcount

NOTE: On local SF cluster, it comes up perfectly fine: http://localhost:8081/wordCount

Does anyone ran into same issue and able to resolve. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.
Nick

Answer (score 0):

19080 is used by SF Explorer (the management web UI), so when you access the app, use it's own port, like you did locally with 8081.

Update to answer follow-up question from comments:

For the Word Count sample, the default port is 8081, see here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/blob/master/Services/WordCount/WordCount.WebService/PackageRoot/ServiceManifest.xml#L25

You can check the port in Service Fabric explorer, like so:
[image]

Comment: Hi Itaysk, Thanks for responding. I already tried using port 8081#: http://tenantname.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com:8081/wordcount (could not post this URL earlier due to limit of 2) but the site could not be reached. Is there any place where I can see what port is exposed inside Service Fabric Explorer for that app. Thanks!

Comment: You can check the port in Service Fabric explorer. For the word count sample, the default port is 8081. I'll update my answer with examples.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of this issue: I needed to setup the load balancer rule so that external request is mapped to the Azure SF's internal TCP port. Appreciate much Itaysk for looking into it.